# MacBook Pro 15 slow after reset, Console full with errors

Tags: macbook-pro, console

Over the last two weeks, my MacBook decided to stop loading pages with the error "server cannot be contacted". As it has been some time, I finally decided to reset the whole thing. It is a complete fresh install.

However, again, it is incredible slow, laggy, network is sometimes not working, animations are lagging and stuttering, I am really annoyed. I did a Diagnosis with the diagnosis utilities before resetting but it showed no problems.
I had a look into the console and there are so many errors going on, I do not even know where to start. Could they be the problem?

Some of the errors:

```
coreduet

Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x7fa686c08d50> (Domain: kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access

com.apple.WebKit.WebContent 

Couldn't write values for keys (NSLinguisticDataAssetsRequestTime
) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x7fbcd6007940> (Domain: kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, User:
kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting
preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or
file-write-data sandbox access

Unknown class <private> in Interface Builder file at path <private>.

0 is not a valid connection ID.

flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
```

Anyone has any idea what I could/should do?

Comment: What specific MacBook Pro 15" are you using?  What version of macOS?

Comment: @Allan it’s the 15 Inch 2015 A1398 with the dedicated R9 card, newest version of macOS 10.15.7